# Android ListView drag & drop with TouchInterceptor: row stay visible

Tags: android, listview

I'm modifying TouchInterceptor class to get an drag & drop listview with onLong touch event handle and I would love some help.

I was able to add an GestureDetector to handle drag row but there is a graphic problem during dragging: the neighbour row take two line when I drag the row.
Here is a screenshots of the problem: https://i.stack.imgur.com/pY0wS.jpg

I'm stuck, anyone?

Here is my code:

```
public class MyTouchInterceptor extends ListView {

    private ImageView mDragView;
    private WindowManager mWindowManager;
    private WindowManager.LayoutParams mWindowParams;
    /**
     * At which position is the item currently being dragged. Note that this
     * takes in to account header items.
     */
    private int mDragPos;
    /**
     * At which position was the item being dragged originally
     */
    private int mSrcDragPos;
    private int mDragPointX;    // at what x offset inside the item did the user grab it
    private int mDragPointY;    // at what y offset inside the item did the user grab it
    private int mXOffset;  // the difference between screen coordinates and coordinates in this view
    private int mYOffset;  // the difference between screen coordinates and coordinates in this view
    private DragListener mDragListener;
    private DropListener mDropListener;
    private RemoveListener mRemoveListener;
    private int mUpperBound;
    private int mLowerBound;
    private int mHeight;
    private GestureDetector mGestureDetector;
    private static final int FLING = 0;
    private static final int SLIDE = 1;
    private static final int TRASH = 2;
    private int mRemoveMode = -1;
    private Rect mTempRect = new Rect();
    private Bitmap mDragBitmap;
    private final int mTouchSlop;
    private int mItemHeightNormal;
    private int mItemHeightExpanded;
    private int mItemHeightHalf;
    private Drawable mTrashcan;

    private final int LINE_THICKNESS = 15;


    public MyTouchInterceptor(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
        super(context, attrs);
        SharedPreferences pref = context.getSharedPreferences("Music", 3);
        mRemoveMode = pref.getInt("deletemode", -1);
        mTouchSlop = ViewConfiguration.get(context).getScaledTouchSlop();
        Resources res = getResources();
        mItemHeightNormal = res.getDimensionPixelSize(R.dimen.normal_height);
        mItemHeightHalf = mItemHeightNormal / 2;
        mItemHeightExpanded = res.getDimensionPixelSize(R.dimen.expanded_height);


        mGestureDetector = new GestureDetector(context, new GestureDetector.SimpleOnGestureListener(){
            @Override
            public void onLongPress(MotionEvent ev) {
                int x = (int) ev.getX();
                int y = (int) ev.getY();
                int itemnum = pointToPosition(x, y);
                if (itemnum == AdapterView.INVALID_POSITION) {
                    return;
                }
                ViewGroup item = (ViewGroup) getChildAt(itemnum - getFirstVisiblePosition());
                mDragPointX = x - item.getLeft();
                mDragPointY = y - item.getTop();
                mXOffset = ((int)ev.getRawX()) - x;
                mYOffset = ((int)ev.getRawY()) - y;
                // The left side of the item is the grabber for dragging the item
                item.setDrawingCacheEnabled(true);
                // Create a copy of the drawing cache so that it does not get recycled
                // by the framework when the list tries to clean up memory
                Bitmap bitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(item.getDrawingCache());

                startDragging(bitmap, x, y);
                mDragPos = itemnum;
                mSrcDragPos = mDragPos;
                mHeight = getHeight();
                int touchSlop = mTouchSlop;
                mUpperBound = Math.min(y - touchSlop, mHeight / 3);
                mLowerBound = Math.max(y + touchSlop, mHeight * 2 /3);
            }



            @Override
            public boolean onFling(MotionEvent e1, MotionEvent e2, float velocityX, float velocityY) {
                if (mDragView != null) {
                    //if (velocityX > 1000) {
                    Rect r = mTempRect;
                    mDragView.getDrawingRect(r);
                    if ( e2.getX() > r.right * 2 / 3) {
                        // fast fling right with release near the right edge of the screen
                        stopDragging();
                        mRemoveListener.remove(mSrcDragPos);
                        unExpandViews(true);
                    }

                    //}
                    // flinging while dragging should have no effect
                    return true;
                }
                return false;
            }


        });
    }



    /*
     * pointToPosition() doesn't consider invisible views, but we
     * need to, so implement a slightly different version.
     */
    private int myPointToPosition(int x, int y) {

        if (y < 0) {
            // when dragging off the top of the screen, calculate position
            // by going back from a visible item
            int pos = myPointToPosition(x, y + mItemHeightNormal);
            if (pos > 0) {
                return pos - 1;
            }
        }

        Rect frame = mTempRect;
        final int count = getChildCount();
        for (int i = count - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
            final View child = getChildAt(i);
            child.getHitRect(frame);
            if (frame.contains(x, y)) {
                return getFirstVisiblePosition() + i;
            }
        }
        return INVALID_POSITION;
    }




    /*
     * Restore size and visibility for all listitems
     */
    private void unExpandViews(boolean deletion) {
        for (int i = 0;; i++) {
            View v = getChildAt(i);
            if (v == null) {
                if (deletion) {
                    // HACK force update of mItemCount
                    int position = getFirstVisiblePosition();
                    int y = getChildAt(0).getTop();
                    setAdapter(getAdapter());
                    setSelectionFromTop(position, y);
                    // end hack
                }
                try {
                    layoutChildren(); // force children to be recreated where needed
                    v = getChildAt(i);
                } catch (IllegalStateException ex) {
                    // layoutChildren throws this sometimes, presumably because we're
                    // in the process of being torn down but are still getting touch
                    // events
                }
                if (v == null) {
                    return;
                }
            }
            ViewGroup.LayoutParams params = v.getLayoutParams();
            params.height = mItemHeightNormal;
            v.setLayoutParams(params);
            v.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        }
    }

    /* Adjust visibility and size to make it appear as though
     * an item is being dragged around and other items are making
     * room for it:
     * If dropping the item would result in it still being in the
     * same place, then make the dragged listitem's size normal,
     * but make the item invisible.
     * Otherwise, if the dragged listitem is still on screen, make
     * it as small as possible and expand the item below the insert
     * point.
     * If the dragged item is not on screen, only expand the item
     * below the current insertpoint.
     */
    private void doExpansion() {
        int childnum = mDragPos - getFirstVisiblePosition();
        if (mDragPos > mSrcDragPos) {
            childnum++;
        }
        int numheaders = getHeaderViewsCount();

        View first = getChildAt(mSrcDragPos - getFirstVisiblePosition());
        for (int i = 0;; i++) {
            View vv = getChildAt(i);
            if (vv == null) {
                break;
            }

            int height = mItemHeightNormal;
            int visibility = View.VISIBLE;
            if (mDragPos < numheaders && i == numheaders) {
                // dragging on top of the header item, so adjust the item below
                // instead
                if (vv.equals(first)) {
                    visibility = View.INVISIBLE;
                } else {
                    height = mItemHeightExpanded;
                }
            } else if (vv.equals(first)) {
                // processing the item that is being dragged
                if (mDragPos == mSrcDragPos || getPositionForView(vv) == getCount() - 1) {
                    // hovering over the original location
                    visibility = View.INVISIBLE;
                } else {
                    // not hovering over it
                    // Ideally the item would be completely gone, but neither
                    // setting its size to 0 nor settings visibility to GONE
                    // has the desired effect.
                    height = 1;
                }
            } else if (i == childnum) {
                if (mDragPos >= numheaders && mDragPos < getCount() - 1) {
                    height = mItemHeightExpanded;
                }
            }
            ViewGroup.LayoutParams params = vv.getLayoutParams();
            params.height = height;
            vv.setLayoutParams(params);
            vv.setVisibility(visibility);
        }
    }


    @Override
    public boolean onTouchEvent(MotionEvent ev) {
        if (mGestureDetector != null) {
            mGestureDetector.onTouchEvent(ev);
        }
        if ((mDragListener != null || mDropListener != null) && mDragView != null) {
            int action = ev.getAction();
            switch (action) {
                case MotionEvent.ACTION_UP:
                case MotionEvent.ACTION_CANCEL:
                    Rect r = mTempRect;
                    mDragView.getDrawingRect(r);
                    stopDragging();
                    if (mRemoveMode == SLIDE && ev.getX() > r.right * 3 / 4) {
                        if (mRemoveListener != null) {
                            mRemoveListener.remove(mSrcDragPos);
                        }
                        unExpandViews(true);
                    } else {
                        if (mDropListener != null && mDragPos >= 0 && mDragPos < getCount()) {
                            mDropListener.drop(mSrcDragPos, mDragPos);
                        }
                        unExpandViews(false);
                    }
                    break;

                case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN:
                case MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE:
                    int x = (int) ev.getX();
                    int y = (int) ev.getY();
                    dragView(x, y);
                    int itemnum = getItemForPosition(y);
                    if (itemnum >= 0) {
                        if (action == MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN || itemnum != mDragPos) {
                            if (mDragListener != null) {
                                mDragListener.drag(mDragPos, itemnum);
                            }
                            mDragPos = itemnum;
                            doExpansion();
                        }
                        int speed = 0;
                        adjustScrollBounds(y);
                        if (y > mLowerBound) {
                            // scroll the list up a bit
                            if (getLastVisiblePosition() < getCount() - 1) {
                                speed = y > (mHeight + mLowerBound) / 2 ? 16 : 4;
                            } else {
                                speed = 1;
                            }
                        } else if (y < mUpperBound) {
                            // scroll the list down a bit
                            speed = y < mUpperBound / 2 ? -16 : -4;
                            if (getFirstVisiblePosition() == 0
                                    && getChildAt(0).getTop() >= getPaddingTop()) {
                                // if we're already at the top, don't try to scroll, because
                                // it causes the framework to do some extra drawing that messes
                                // up our animation
                                speed = 0;
                            }
                        }
                        if (speed != 0) {
                            smoothScrollBy(speed, 30);
                        }
                    }
                    break;
            }
            return true;
        }
        return super.onTouchEvent(ev);
    }

    private void startDragging(Bitmap bm, int x, int y) {
        stopDragging();

        …
        mDragView = v;
    }

    private void dragView(int x, int y) {
        if (mRemoveMode == SLIDE) {
            float alpha = 1.0f;
            int width = mDragView.getWidth();
            if (x > width / 2) {
                alpha = ((float)(width - x)) / (width / 2);
            }
            mWindowParams.alpha = alpha;
        }

        if (mRemoveMode == FLING || mRemoveMode == TRASH) {
            mWindowParams.x = x - mDragPointX + mXOffset;
        } else {
            mWindowParams.x = 0;
        }
        mWindowParams.y = y - mDragPointY + mYOffset;
        mWindowManager.updateViewLayout(mDragView, mWindowParams);

        if (mTrashcan != null) {
            int width = mDragView.getWidth();
            if (y > getHeight() * 3 / 4) {
                mTrashcan.setLevel(2);
            } else if (width > 0 && x > width / 4) {
                mTrashcan.setLevel(1);
            } else {
                mTrashcan.setLevel(0);
            }
        }
    }

    private void stopDragging() {
        if (mDragView != null) {
            mDragView.setVisibility(GONE);
            WindowManager wm = (WindowManager)getContext().getSystemService(Context.WINDOW_SERVICE);
            wm.removeView(mDragView);
            mDragView.setImageDrawable(null);
            mDragView = null;
        }
        if (mDragBitmap != null) {
            mDragBitmap.recycle();
            mDragBitmap = null;
        }
        if (mTrashcan != null) {
            mTrashcan.setLevel(0);
        }
    }

    public void setTrashcan(Drawable trash) {
        mTrashcan = trash;
        mRemoveMode = TRASH;
    }

    public void setDragListener(DragListener l) {
        mDragListener = l;
    }

    public void setDropListener(DropListener l) {
        mDropListener = l;
    }

    public void setRemoveListener(RemoveListener l) {
        mRemoveListener = l;
    }

    public interface DragListener {
        void drag(int from, int to);
    }
    public interface DropListener {
        void drop(int from, int to);
    }
    public interface RemoveListener {
        void remove(int which);
    }
```

Comment: That's a LOT of code. Have you narrowed down at all where the error might be occurring? I'd recommend [paring this down to as little code as possible while still reproducing the problem](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: Thanks @AndrewLaPrise I narrowed it